# Is this server IP + PORT reachable from my server? (using Telnet)

Tags: networking, telnet

I am not so into networking and I have the following doubt.
I have to test if a specific port on a server it can be reached from another server (or if there is something that is blocking the request as a firewall).

I am trying to use telnet on this port:

```
telnet SERVER_IP PORT.
```

This is what I am obtaining:

[image]

So what it means? Is it reachable? The thing that makes me suspicious is this **Trying SERVER_IP...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that it is trying to connect.

A successful connection message would look like:

```
Connected to www.example.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you wait long enough for unsuccessful connection, you might get error messages like:

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port 1111: Connect failed
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Question: Do you really have a point `.` after the port number?